# Authentication using Tomcat realm or Facebook login

Tags: facebook, tomcat, authentication

I have a web application that authenticates users through the standard Tomcat mechanism. More specifically, I configured a `JDBCRealm` that points to my own user and role tables and I am using form-based authentication, which submits the user details to the `j_security_check` action (as `j_username` and `j_password`). The security constraints are configured in my `web.xml` file.

Now, I'd like to provide users with a second login option: Facebook. I've already configured Facebook login using their Javascript SDK, but I'm having problems to integrate both login options. Ideally, when the user logs into Facebook, I would have to simulate an authentication  in the Tomcat realm as well to make sure the Facebook user behaves as a regular Tomcat user. That means I also have to register the Facebook user in my own user table.

My first idea was to register the user in my own user table right after they finish their Facebook login (using an Ajax request, for example). When this request finishes, I would be able to trigger a manual submit to `j_security_check`.

The Facebook response includes a user `id` and a `token` that I could use. However, I don't know what information to use as `j_password`. I don't even know if using form-authentication is the best option any more.

What would be the best way to integrate both login options?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use a Combined Realm: See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#CombinedRealm

Realm 1 should be JDBCRealm, then implement realm 2 (FacebookRealm). You might change the order, based on which one is the most frequently used. See Tomcat docs for how to implement a realm.

Of course you don't have a password in FacebookRealm, but you could do the following trick:
JDBCRealm:
username = username/userId in your application
password = password
FacebookRealm:
username = username/userId in your application
password = unique user id provided by Facebook

This could allow users to log in with whatever method they want.

Basically, this could be a possible use case for logging in through FacebookRealm (first steps might be a little bit different with JS SDK, but the idea is similar):
1. User is sent, through a link, to Facebook for authentication.
2. Facebook redirects to your server with a token.
3. Your server makes a Facebook call to verify the authenticity of the user.
4. Your server knows that it's a valid user, so it calls login(username, facebookUserId) method from Servlet. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
4.1. Make sure "username" and "facebookUserId" exist in your database before calling the login method.
5. Tomcat FacebookRealm will just perform a database query for that username and id.

I hope this gives you more insights about how this could be done.
Other options could be through Apache Shiro, Spring Security or probably others as well.